# How to efficiently read a large file with a custom newline character using Python?

Tags: python

We have a huge `.csv` file but it doesn't seem to really be a csv.

The line endings are `\tl\n`.
The text between this newline character sometimes has "real" newline characters. We don't want to split on those.

We currently do it using `awk`.

```
awk_code = r'BEGIN{ RS="""(\tl\n)"""; FS="\t"} { print "\42"$1"\42,\42"$2"\42,\42\42\42"$3"\42\42\42,\n";}'
bash_command_awk = f"awk '{awk_code}' {input_file_path} > {output_path}"
awk_command_output = subprocess.check_output(bash_command_awk,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

I'm trying to find an efficient way of doing it directly in Python and tried passing a custom newline into the `.open()` command.

```
def process_without_putting_file_in_RAM(file_to_process):
    with file_to_process.open(encoding="utf-8", newline="\tl\n") as csv_file:
        for line in csv.reader(csv_file):
```

However, I quickly learned newline arg only accepts one of the default characters.

How can I efficiently process this file containing the weird line ending?

Comment: Any reason why you just can't ignore the last column?

Comment: Hi Keith. I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you talking about the `awk` code? I only understand the lineterminator and linebreak sections.  I haven't even paid attention to the rest yet.

Comment: Sorry I was assuming the file is tab delimited. Any reason why you just can't the ignore last two characters in the line as it's read in? line[:-2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function which can handle multi-character newline between chunks correctly

```
def line_splitter(file, newline, chunk_size=4096):
    tail = ''
    while True:
        chunk = file.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk:
            if tail:
                yield tail
            break
        lines = (tail + chunk).split(newline)
        tail = lines.pop(0)
        if lines:
            yield tail
            tail = lines.pop()
            yield from lines
```

another version which, although it doesn't make copies of whole chunks didn't prove faster. It will be marginally faster for large chunks. Do not use chunk_size less than newline size :)

```
def line_splitter(file, newline, chunk_size=4096):
    tail = ''
    while True:
        chunk = file.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk:
            if tail:
                yield tail
            break
        lines = chunk.split(newline)
        tail = (tail + lines[0]).split(newline)
        if len(tail) > 1:
            lines[0] = tail[1]
        else:
            del lines[0]
        tail = tail[0]
        if lines:
            yield tail
            tail = lines.pop()
            yield from lines
```

The caller should be like:

```
with longabstract_file.open() as f:
    for line in line_splitter(f, "\tl\n"):
        if line: # ignore blank lines
            print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks @panda-34. I'm going to test these and get back to you. For now I removed the checkmark from my answer.

Comment: Thanks again @panda-34 for catching the bug. You first solution is great. This is now the accepted answer. 

Comment: For anyone following along I deleted my original, buggy, answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your csv is a comma or space delimited, not tab, what you were looking for is [`lineterminator` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator), but there's no need for that since it's automatically assumed `'\n'` is a line break. From the doc:

> Note: The reader is hard-coded to recognise either `'\r'` or `'\n'` as
>   end-of-line, and ignores `lineterminator`. This behavior may change in
>   the future.

so what you can do is add string method `.replace()` to get rid of `'\tl'` like this

```
def process_without_putting_file_in_RAM(file_to_process):
    with file_to_process.open(encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
        for line in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=","):
            print(line[-1].replace('\tl', ''))
```

Comment: Thanks @cryptonome.  That made sense for the question as posted.  I added some new information regarding the fact that "real" line terminators may be found inside the custom line terminator.  We don't want to split on those.

Comment: in principle that `replace('\tl\n', '\n')` method can be used on lines with a file handler instead of list generated by the `csv.reader`, and to make it more efficient, use a generator (most probably already is a generator). _but_, depending on how big the file is (or how much files to process), i'd say awk will be faster than pure python. i'll see if i can test a 600+ MB csv later, but you'd want to do your own test on awk timing & include in your post.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use `pandas`. Specifically [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) using `lineterminator` and `chunksize` parameters:

```
import pandas as pd

batch_size = 10000
new_line_str = '\tl\n'
iterator_df = pd.read_csv(file_to_process, chunksize=batch_size, lineterminator=new_line_str)
for chunk in iterator_df:
    # process chunk here
```

Comment: I get an error `Only 1-length line terminators supported`.