# How to efficiently read and delete a specific line of a large file with a custom newline character using Python (3.9 preferred)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, large-files, file-manipulation

[Similar to this question, but slightly more complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52787585/how-to-efficiently-read-a-large-file-with-a-custom-newline-character-using-pytho)

I have a large txt file, that looks something like this:

"
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA.BBBBBBBBBBBBBB.CCCCCCCCCCCCCC.DDDDDDDDDDDDDD.EEEEEEEEEEEEEE.FFFFFFFFFFFFFF.GGGGGGGGGGGGGG.HHHHHHHHHHHHHH.IIIIIIIIIIIIII.JJJJJJJJJJJJJJ.KKKKKKKKKKKKKK.
"

Each line break is a ".", the file ends in a linebreak, each line is exactly 14 characters long.
[GollyJer's answer to the mentioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54962532) is good, but I have a few extra requirements:

1. I'd like to be able to input a specific line number and have that
   one line be returned
2. Then I'd like the line that is read to be deleted from the file.

I can't have the real txt be loaded into RAM as it's over 600GB

I don't know where to begin with altering the code to do this.
Is this even possible? How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: AFAIK you can't really "delete" a "line" (it's not a line, you just have some delimiter, which isn't a newline, it's something else) from a file, unless it is at the end (you can truncate it).  You could mark lines as deleted and eventually resize the whole file, I suppose.

Comment: Anyway, you can efficiently retrieve it, since it is a fixed-width format. You can just `seek` and `read` by `(14 + 1) * record_number`.

Answer (score 0):

I might explore the walrus operator to clean this up and I really have no idea if this is going to be "fast enough". The idea is to read upto the point you want. read/print the stuff to delete then read the rest:

```py
line_to_delete = 2
with open("in.txt", "rt") as file_in:
    with open("out.txt", "wt") as file_out:
        file_out.write(file_in.read(15 * (line_to_delete -1)))
        print(file_in.read(15))
        file_out.write(file_in.read())
```

I think that might be memory intensive so you might produce a more streamy result by doing:

```py
line_to_delete = 2

with open("in.txt", "rt") as file_in:
    current_line = 1
    with open("out.txt", "wt") as file_out:
        while True:
            line = file_in.read(15)
            if not line:
                break

            if current_line == line_to_delete:
                print(line)
            else:
                file_out.write(line)

            current_line += 1
```

both print `BBBBBBBBBBBBBB.` and produce a file like:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA.CCCCCCCCCCCCCC.DDDDDDDDDDDDDD.EEEEEEEEEEEEEE.FFFFFFFFFFFFFF.GGGGGGGGGGGGGG.HHHHHHHHHHHHHH.IIIIIIIIIIIIII.JJJJJJJJJJJJJJ.KKKKKKKKKKKKKK.
```